# How do I add onto the width of an existing div by clicking a button with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Basically, I have a div with a width of 200px and I'd like to increase the width of the div by a certain number of pixels every time I click a button. How would I go about doing this? I've been at it for awhile and all I can get it to do is completely change the width of the div to a new amount instead of increasing it every time I click the button.

```
function changeSize() {
var newwidth;
var width = document.getElementById("box1").style.width;

newwidth = width += "300px";
document.getElementById("box1").style.width = newwidth;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function changeSize() {
    var newwidth;
    var width = document.getElementById("box1").style.width;
    width = parseInt(width) + 300;
    newwidth = width + "px";
    document.getElementById("box1").style.width = newwidth;
}
```

I think `style.width` returns the value plus the "px" at the end. I could be wrong. But at any rate, you can't include the "px" in the addition because it's not a number. But you can use the `+` to concatenate the "px" to the value after the addition is done.

`parseInt` is a built-in JS function that return the integer value of the string of numbers it finds starting at the beginning of the string and stopping at the first non-numeric character.

**update**

If you're getting the `parseInt` error it is because the width value has not be initialized with a starting value. You need to check if the value is null. Here is a more "bulletproof" version:

```
function changeSize() { 
    var box = document.getElementById("box1");

    //make sure box is not null, and the style attribute is valid, and can be set
    if (box && box.style) { 
        if (!box.style.width) {
            //init the value the first time
            box.style.width = "210px";
        } else {
            //get the current value and increment
            var width = parseInt(box.style.width) + 10; 
            box.style.width = width + "px";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It still isn't working, unfortunately. In the console I get this error, "Error in parsing value for 'width'.  Declaration dropped."

Comment: function changeSize() {
    var newwidth;
    var width = document.getElementById("box1").style.width = '200px';
    width = parseInt(width) + 10;
    newwidth = width + "px";
    document.getElementById("box1").style.width = newwidth;
}

This works for me and doesn't give me the parseInt error but now when I click the button it only adds 10px once and I'd like it to add 10px to the current width every time I click the button. Any ideas there?